# Create copy of .xlsm as .xlsx on save

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create backup copy of workbook .xlsm and save it as .xlsx

due to the same issue as here: [Run time error '1004': Copy method of worksheet class failed - Temp file issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180966/run-time-error-1004-copy-method-of-worksheet-class-failed-temp-file-issue)
I cannot use SaveCopyAs along with changing format of file

My workaround was to

1. create new copy of .xlsm file
2. open this new copy
3. save it as .xlsx
4. Close .xlsx file
5. Remove file from step 1

this is my code

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    'define variables
    Dim backupfolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim xlsxStrFileName As String
    Dim fullPath As String
    Dim xlsxFullPath As String
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    'get timestamp
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")

    'construct full path to backup file which will be later converted to .xlsx
    backupfolder = "c:\work\excel macro\delete\"

    strFileName = "Test_iz_" & dt & ".xlsm"
    fullPath = "" & backupfolder & strFileName

    xlsxStrFileName = "Test_iz_" & dt & ".xlsx"
    xlsxFullPath = "" & backupfolder & xlsxStrFileName

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=fullPath

    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(fullPath)

    wkb.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xlsxFullPath, FileFormat:=51 'saves the file
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Kill fullPath
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    MsgBox "Backup saved: " & xlsxFullPath
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fullPath

End Sub
```

My problem is that i always end up in ErrorHandler, even though i got expected result

When i comment out line 2

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
```

error Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
on Debug, it points to row with the code

```
wkb.Activate
```

and .xlsm file is not deleted

I guess the problem is that when i create new copy of xlsm file and save it, this entire code would be executed one more time and that issue is there somewhere, but i cannot find it.
Thank you

Comment: Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the line where you save the backup copy (remember to set it back to True).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked on my computer:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
'define variables
Dim backupfolder As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim xlsxStrFileName As String
Dim fullPath As String
Dim xlsxFullPath As String
Dim wkb As Workbook

'get timestamp
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")

'construct full path to backup file which will be later converted to .xlsx
backupfolder = "c:\work\excel macro\delete\"

strFileName = "Test_iz_" & dt & ".xlsm"
fullPath = "" & backupfolder & strFileName

xlsxStrFileName = "Test_iz_" & dt & ".xlsx"
xlsxFullPath = "" & backupfolder & xlsxStrFileName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fullPath, FileFormat:=52
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xlsxFullPath, FileFormat:=51 'saves the file
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Kill fullPath
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "An error occured " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
MsgBox "Backup saved: " & xlsxFullPath
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fullPath
End Sub
```

Cheers,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but here's the code I use to save an .xlsx copy of an .xslm file. The key is to create a copy of one of the worksheets and then save it:

```
Sub SaveCopy()

    Dim filename
    Dim path As String
    Dim dt As String
    
    If TimeValue(Now) < TimeValue("12:00:00 PM") Then
        meridian = "AM"
    Else
        meridian = "PM"
    End If
    
    path = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Exports\"
    dt = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm")
    fname = "EXPORT " & dt & meridian
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Sheet5.Copy
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs filename:=path & fname, FileFormat:=51
        .Close
    End With
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```